# Mongodb revoke access to connect test database

Tags: mongodb, authentication, amazon-ec2, database, nosql

I have an ec2 instance with mongodb 3.2.0 installed. I have a user with admin access. I can connect with user and perform operation remotely. But any one can connect the database test from remote if he knows the ip like mongo 11.11.11.11. Although he will not able to make any operations, but I want to restrict this access so that only user with credentials can connect to server.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create users and grant roles to those users, for example:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

then you need to start your server with the --auth parameter

```
mongod --auth
```

More Information [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)

Comment: already done. but user still connect to database without credentials but cant perform operations.

Comment: e.g mongo x.x.x.x   my requirement is no one can connect the server without login details.

Comment: how do you start your server. Can you provide de command line you use?.

Comment: mongod --auth   i am running it on linux screen

Comment: are you using a configuration file? /etc/mongod.conf

Comment: i have set some parameters in conf files. Is there any parameter that is required to set to revoke the connect without username and password

Comment: Check if you have the security.authorization parameter disabled in you config file. This may be the problem.

Comment: there is no parameter name like this in the /etc/mongodb.conf file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101791/discussion-between-orejano-and-as1992).